# Create an array of strings of every lines

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, string, react-hooks

I'm new to React.js (using hooks) and want to learn by simply coding,
my question is I want to fetch data for example from ksngfr.com/something.txt and the data I'm getting from there is '2005-07-09 03:05 1:74539
2:29735 3:95426 4:35489 ...' and it is '.txt', I want to put them into array (key, value), and have access to them for each separately, I found this 'loadStrings()' is that good for this specific purpose(mostly in old sites is talked about that) or is there another better in React.js (hooks)?

data i'm fetching:

[image]

English is not my mother language so sorry for mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating the array from text by spliting it using delimiter and then iterating on array to add key/value to object

```js
const str = "1:345 2:455 3:678";
 var data = str.split(' '); //create array from text by spliting it 
 const obj = {};
data.forEach(d=>{
var key = d.split(':')[0]; //extract the key from each data
var value = d.split(':')[1]; //extract the value from each data
obj[key] = value;
});
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: for some reason the array what i'm getting looks different, it looks like this : ["2005-07-09", "03:05↵1:74539↵2:29735↵3:95426↵4:35489↵"]

Answer (score 1):

**String manipulation**

You can use standard string manipulation to pass an array of `[key, value]` pairs to `Object.fromEntries()` which will return an object.

```js
const str = "1:345 2:455 3:678";

const object = Object.fromEntries(
  str.split(' ').map(d => ([k, v] = d.split(':'), [k, v])));

console.log(object);
```

***Edit***

It looks like you are now looking for an array of full matches, and that your initial string is less regular. To accommodate this, without knowing the specifics of your string, I think a regular expression is going to serve you better. This snippet still captures elements on both sides of the `:` if you want to use it to create an object, but here only the full match is being `map()`ed to the final array.

```js
const str = "2005-07-09 03:05↵1:74539↵2:29735\n\r3:95426↵4:35489\n\r";

const regex = /(\d+)[:|-](\d+)(?:[:|-](\d+))?(?=\D|$)/g
const array = Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), ([m]) => m);

console.log(array);
```

---

**Regular expression with matchAll()**

You could also use [`matchAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) with a simple regex to return an iterator of key/value matches.

These can be passed to [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and mapped to an array of `[key, value]` pairs which can then be passed to [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to yield your final object.

```js
const str = "1:345 2:455 3:678";

const regex = /(\d+):(\d+)(?=\s|$)/g;
const object = Object.fromEntries(
    Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), ([_, key, value]) => [key, value]));
    
console.log(object);
```

**Explanation**

Here is a step by step implementation of the above one liner.

```
// input
const str = "1:345 2:455 3:678";

// define regular expression
const regex = /(\d+):(\d+)(?=\s|$)/g;

// return iterator from matchAll() called on input passing regex
const matchIterator = str.matchAll(regex);

// pass the iterator to Array.from() and use built in map() 
// to return a [key, value] array using destructuring.
const keyValueArr = Array.from(matchIterator, ([_, key, value]) => [key, value]);

// pass the array to Object.fromEntries()
const finalObject = Object.fromEntries(keyValueArr);
```

The [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

- `(\d+)` any number of consecutive digits (captured)
- `:`     directly followed by a colon (not captured)
- `(\d+)` directly followed by another group of digits (captured)
- `(?=\s|$)` lookahead for whitespace or end of line
- `/g` global flag to find all occurrences.

The return value from  `matchAll()` will be an iterator of arrays of the shape `['full match', 'capture group 1', 'capture group 2']` (eg: `['1:345', '1', '345']`)

---

Comment: thank you for good explanation but i ended up using answer of the other user, which works BUT the array looks different, i did like this :         {(daattaa = data?.split(" "))}

        {console.log(daattaa)}, and for some reason the array what i'm getting looks different, it looks like this : ["2005-07-09", "03:05↵1:74539↵2:29735↵3:95426↵4:35489↵"] , any idea what those characters are ? why there isnt comma instead of those characters ? (if you write anwer dont delete your previous answer, it may help other cuz its very detailed)

Comment: Those are return symbols indicating that there should be a line break.

Comment: yes but everything should be inside commas (now there is just one comma), it should look like this ["2005-07-09", "03:05","1:74539","2:29735","3:95426","4:35489"]

Comment: Your array is only two elements long. The second element is a string with `↵` characters instead of spaces, so it didn't get `split()`. You'll need to split it again on the `↵` characters `split('↵')`, or better yet `data.replace(/↵/g, ' ').split(' ')`

Comment: do you mean like this :  daattaa = data?.replace(/↵/g, " ").split(" ");
  console.log(daattaa); if so its not working i get same result

Comment: i added a picture of how my data looks like, if it helps